# How to disable http trace/track method in apache

Tags: apache, http, trace

I am trying to disable http trace/track method in apache

I tried to write `TraceEnable Off` in `httpd.conf` file. As i am new to this, am not able to understand where to write this and will there be any impact due to this.

Also, I have below rewrite engine in `httpd.conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Not able to understand and test whether http trace is disable or not.

Comment: TraceEnable Off is enough, define it in server config context. Why do you ask about any dependency? or Anything. You didn't say which problems you had when you tried "TraceEnable Off". You may also want to read the httpd docs about it. [TraceEnable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#traceenable)

Comment: I just added TraceEnable off in httpd.socf file and then ran a vulnerability scan and issue has been resolved

@ezra-s

Comment: We had some vulnerability issues in our application, however we had RewriteEngine on still HTTP trace method was enable this was the problem, i wanted to disable it .